# get indices of numpy multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
```

I'm trying to get the indices of `arr` when `arr==1`.

I thought this would work but it doesn't give the expected output:

```
>>> np.where(arr==1)
   (array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: it is giving you the expected output you get 1 at `[0][0][0]`

Comment: sorry, you are right, I misunderstood the output... By the way how would you do this for multiple numbers like `arr==1 or 2 or 3`?

Comment: `arr[ np.where( arr=1 )]` should display `1`.  `where/nonzero` gives a tuple of arrays suitable for indexing.  Here its 3 arrays since `arr` is 3d.

Answer (score 1):

If you change arr:

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,1],[7,8]]])
```

and you will get

```
np.where(arr==1)
# (array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 1]))
```

it is mean:

```
arr[0][0][0] == 1
arr[1][0][0] == 1
arr[1][0][1] == 1
```

When you want display coordinate in one row:

```
np.array(np.where(arr==1)).T
# array([[0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: `arr[1,0,1]` is nicer looking `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple numbers, you can mix np.where and [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) functions:

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([1,2,3])
arr = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])

loc_i, loc_j, loc_k = np.where(np.isin(arr, val))
print('locations:')
[print(f'({loc_i[i]},{loc_j[i]},{loc_k[i]})') for i in range(loc_i.size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting option is to use *argwhere* to get indices of elements in question.

To present a more instructive example, assume that we want indices of your *arr*
where the value is *<= 3*.

The code to get them is `np.argwhere(arr <= 3)`, getting:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

​Meaning that the "wanted" elemens are:

```
arr[0, 0, 0], arr[0, 0, 1], arr[0, 1, 0],
```

If you want e.g. to print indices of the "wanted" elements and their values,
you can run:

```
for ind in np.argwhere(arr <= 3):
    print(f'{ind}: {arr.__getitem__(tuple(ind))}')
```

The result is:

```
[0 0 0]: 1
[0 0 1]: 2
[0 1 0]: 3
```

Note also that my code works regardless of the number of dimensions in
your array, whereas in other solutions the number of dimensions is
somehow "fixed" in the code.

Comment: All `argwhere` does is `np.transpose(np.where(...))`